# one of the networks on a 2-interface machine no longer reachable

Tags: networking, centos, iptables

I have a centos machine with two network interfaces for 162.* and 172.* subnetworks. The machine used to work properly but as of today the 172.* network is no longer reachable. I've no idea what has changed, what the configuration was before. Below is the output of ifconfig, ip route and ip link as well as the content of the interface files under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

```
ifconfig -a
eno16777984: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 162.70.42.93  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 162.70.42.255
        ether 00:50:56:ba:b0:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1935793  bytes 195710508 (186.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 16501  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 638906  bytes 47382225 (45.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno33557248: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feba:6875  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:ba:68:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 147161  bytes 8837081 (8.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 639  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8098  bytes 1436275 (1.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 318746  bytes 17084987 (16.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 318746  bytes 17084987 (16.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


ip route
default via 162.70.42.1 dev eno16777984  proto static  metric 100 
162.70.42.0/24 dev eno16777984  proto kernel  scope link  src 162.70.42.93  metric 100

ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno16777984: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:ba:b0:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno33557248: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:ba:68:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno33557248:
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME=eno33557248
UUID="e157d343-3acb-4498-8ab2-83251bf5e098"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR=00:50:56:BA:68:75
IPADDR=172.16.3.2
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=172.16.3.1

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ ifcfg-eno16777984:
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eno16777984"
UUID="e157d343-3acb-4498-8ab2-83251bf5e098"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR="00:50:56:BA:B0:83"
DNS1="162.70.113.10"
DNS2="162.70.113.11"
IPADDR=162.70.42.93
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=162.70.42.1
ZONE=public
```

ifconfig eno33557248 down

```
Feb 16 17:01:46 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): link disconnected
Feb 16 17:01:46 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [30 20 40]
```

ifconfig eno33557248 up

```
eb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat kernel: vmxnet3 0000:0b:00.0 eno33557248: intr type 3, mode 0, 5 vectors allocated
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat kernel: vmxnet3 0000:0b:00.0 eno33557248: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): link connected
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  Auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'.
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (529d729a-48e0-4ecb-94d0-07dc43dca703)
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  Activation (eno33557248) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  dhclient started with pid 12676
Feb 16 17:01:54 sassy-admin-uat dhclient[12676]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno33557248 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x74c85128)
Feb 16 17:01:56 sassy-admin-uat avahi-daemon[621]: Registering new address record for fe80::250:56ff:feba:6875 on eno33557248.*.
Feb 16 17:01:59 sassy-admin-uat dhclient[12676]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno33557248 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x74c85128)
Feb 16 17:02:04 sassy-admin-uat dhclient[12676]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno33557248 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x74c85128)
Feb 16 17:02:17 sassy-admin-uat dhclient[12676]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno33557248 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x74c85128)
Feb 16 17:02:34 sassy-admin-uat dhclient[12676]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno33557248 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x74c85128)
Feb 16 17:02:40 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <warn>  (eno33557248): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Feb 16 17:02:40 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> timeout
Feb 16 17:02:40 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 12676
Feb 16 17:02:40 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): DHCPv4 state changed timeout -> done
Feb 16 17:02:40 sassy-admin-uat NetworkManager[692]: <info>  (eno33557248): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
```

Comment: Obviously your second virtual NIC doesn't have an IP address. Check the system's network configuration and logs.

Comment: Added the content of the network interfaces as well as the output of ifconfig up/down under /var/log/messages. I can see ifconfig up fails with a "dhcp4 request timeout" so it's probably the root cause. However I still need help. I did not configure this machine from scratch, I'm not aware of any config changes and I'm not seeing any dhcp config for either interface. Both IPs appear to be configured statically.

Comment: At this point I would have a chat with whoever runs the ESXi server.

Comment: They did in fact just recently upgrade the VM infrastructure. Adding IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
ended up fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that IPv4 (inet) address in the output of your ifconfig command.  It looks like your eno33557248 interface only has an IPv6 (inet6) address.

```
eno16777984: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 162.70.42.93  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 162.70.42.255
        ether 00:50:56:ba:b0:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eno33557248: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 .
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feba:6875  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:ba:68:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

If you are using static addressing, not DHCP, take a look at your ipcfg (might be /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ipcfg-eno33557248) to make sure the address is configured.  Then, "ifconfig eno33557248 down" and "ifconfig eno33557248 up" should bring it back.

Comment: Thx can you see my updated answer and a comment above.